# Select a range of rows as various columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server, we have the next situation: there is a table that looks like this.

```
Id    | Code  | Value
----- | ----- | -----
1     |    10 |     0
2     |    20 |     0
3     |    30 |     0
4     |    40 |     0
5     |    50 |     0
6     |    60 |     0
7     |    70 |     0
8     |    80 |     0
9     |    90 |     0
10    |   100 |     0
```

And I would like to create a view of this table to show it like this:

```
Code1 | Value1 | Code2 | Value2 | Code3 | Value3 | Code4 | Value4
----- | ------ | ----- | ------ | ----- | ------ | ----- | ------
   10 |      0 |    40 |      0 |    70 |      0 |   100 |      0
   20 |      0 |    50 |      0 |    80 |      0 | 
   30 |      0 |    60 |      0 |    90 |      0 |
```

I have tried with subqueries but always returns more than one rows, and I don't think I can use a PIVOT in this case... How can I do it?

Comment: That is a task for a reporting engine or front-end application, not the database server; there is no data relationship in the view you want. But you could probably hack it together with multiple `pivot`s and `join`ing on the intervals you want between the `Code`s in the different columns... it seems like a lot of hassle to do presentation in the wrong place, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that has to done in application side. Here is a way to do it in sql(static approach) with batch size as 3

```
DECLARE @batch INT =3

SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
       LEFT JOIN Yourtable b
              ON a.[Id] = ( ( b.[Id] - 1 ) % @batch ) + 1
                 AND a.[Id] <> b.[Id]
                 AND b.[Id] BETWEEN @batch + 1 AND @batch * 2
       LEFT JOIN Yourtable c
              ON a.[Id] = ( ( c.[Id] - 1 ) % @batch ) + 1
                 AND a.[Id] <> c.[Id]
                 AND c.[Id] BETWEEN ( @batch * 2 ) + 1 AND @batch * 3
       LEFT JOIN Yourtable d
              ON a.[Id] = ( ( d.[Id] - 1 ) % @batch ) + 1
                 AND a.[Id] <> d.[Id]
                 AND d.[Id] BETWEEN ( @batch * 3 ) + 1 AND @batch * 4
WHERE  a.[Id] <= @batch
```

- **[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/ZZKFP24822)**